# How do I set permissions to write files in Inno Installer?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an .exe which creates multiple files.
The application works just fine in my folder but when I install the exe and neccessary files with the installer generated by inno installer, my program crashes. I suspect that the .exe does not have permissions to create file in the installation folder.
How do I set permissions to write files in Inno Installer?
Thanks

Comment: Before going down the permissions road I would generate an install log and confirm that is indeed the problem. I'm not as familiar with Inno Setup but it looks like /log=yes should generate a log when launched from the command line
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setuplogging

Comment: i will try that, but it definitely is something with permissions... because there is no problem at all when i install the .exe on the desktop for exmaple. But when i install the .exe in Program Files(x86) there seem to be problems sadly

Comment: Your application should not be writing to Program Files (x86) after installation. That folder , along with the Windows folder, have required administrator privileges since Windows Vista. If your app needs to write to that folder, you should fix your application's code so that it doesn't.

Comment: I misunderstood then. I was thinking that your setup.exe was failing to install to Program Files. You're talking about your actual installed application run time trying to create these files. As Luca stated your application should create files into the %appdata% folder.